# Почему не работает код на C?

Tags: c

Начал изучать C.
Элементарная программа:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    float a;
    float b;
    scanf("%f", a);
    scanf("%f", b);
    printf("Result: %f", pow(a, b));
}
```

`Exit status -1`. Почему не работает так, как я запланировал? Почему в выводе не указана ошибка? Что исправить?

Comment: Что такое "Exit status -1"? Откуда вы взяли этот "Exit status"?

Comment: @AnT вывод в консоли

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Кратко:

```
scanf("%f", &a);
scanf("%f", &b);
```

Вы должны передавать *адрес* переменной, куда писать считываемое значение. У вас пишет по случайному адресу, в который преобразуется значение из переменной `a` (а потом `b`, если до этого дойдет и программа не рухнет раньше).

Но не верится, что это не было написано большими буквами в учебнике, который вы читаете - что нужно передавать адрес переменной. И что компилятор вас не предупреждал о возможной проблеме...

Answer (score 4):

Формально ваша ошибка - ошибка *времени выполнения*. Поэтому ни в каком "выводе" ее быть не должно. Никто кроме вас ошибки времени выполнения в "вывод" поместить не может. Однако большинство современных компиляторов все таки заметят эту распространенную ошибку и сообщат о ней хотя бы предупреждением. Может быть вы просто проигнорировали диагностические сообщения компилятора?

Должно быть

```
scanf("%f", &a);
```